# What does it take to enter the Red Bull Air Race?

Tags: flight-training, air-race

Starting from being a newly minted private pilot, what are the steps I would have to accomplish in order to eventually qualify for and compete in the Red Bull Air Race? Assuming I put most of my time into the endeavour and progressed at a reasonably fast pace, how long would it take me?

Comment: I'd probably start with 10,000 hours and a correspondingly large sum of money.

Comment: Not to mention balls of absolute steel.

Comment: I've voted to close for too broad. An answer to the title question has been given by @Jamiec. However, in the body, the OP states he wants to know the process starting from the time the new pilot has just received their PPL. The steps to go from that point to one of, if not the, single most intensive and challenging air race there is would simply be unanswerable in any meaningful way in this forum.

Comment: @CGCampbell - FWIW I totally agree this is too broad.

Answer (score 7):

According to their [about page](http://www.redbullairrace.com/en_GB/article/rules-and-principles)

> New pilots who wish to participate in the World Championship must first fulfil the minimum criteria set by the Red Bull Air Race Committee, which include top achievements in international flying competitions organised by the FAI. They must also be active aerobatic air display pilots. Eligible pilots that prove their skills at the Red Bull Air Race Qualification Camp can achieve the Red Bull Air Race Restricted Superlicence. Once they have the Restricted Superlicence, they then qualify to take part in the Red Bull Air Race World Championship in the Challenger Cup.

So I would suggest if this is something that interests you, you begin with some instruction in aerobatic flying - a discipline which in itself is quite tough. To find the next qualification camp, I would suggest contacting red bull air race directly. It seems they run annual qualifications, most recently held in Texas, USA.

The amount of time it would take is impossible to measure, or even speculate.